# Use Post to change page

Tags: python, html, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been using Selenium for some time to scrape a website but for some reasons it doesn't work anymore. I was using Selenium because you need to interact with the site to flip through pages (ie: click on a next button).

As a solution, I was thinking of using Post method from Requests. I'm not sure if its doable since I've never used the Post method, and since I not familiar with what it does (though I kind of understand the general idea).

My code would look something like that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent":
           "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10 11 5) "
           "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
           "Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.centris.ca/fr/propriete~a-vendre?view=Thumbnail"

def infinity():
    while True:
        yield

c = 0
urls = []
for i in infinity():
    c += 1
    page = list(str(soup.find("li",{"class":"pager-current"}).text).split())
    pageTot = int("".join(page[-2:])) # Check the total number of page
    if c <= pageTot: # Scrape the first page
        if c <= 1:
            req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        else:
            pass
            # This is where I'm stuck but ideally I'd be using Post method in some way 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,"lxml")
        for link in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"a-more-detail"}):
            try: # For each page scrape ads url
                urls.append("https://www.centris.ca" + link["href"])
            except KeyError:
                pass
    else: # When all pages are scrape exit the loop
        break

for url in list(dict.fromkeys(urls)):
    pass # do stuff
```

This is what is going on when you click next on the webpage:

This is the Request (the startPosition begins at 0 on page 1 and increase by leaps of 12)
[image]

And this is part of the Reponse:

```
{"d":{"Message":"","Result":{"html": [...], "count":34302,"inscNumberPerPage":12,"title":""},"Succeeded":true}}
```

With that information is it possible to use the Post method to scrape every pages ? And how could I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick. I've added duplicate filtering logic to avoid printing duplicate links. The script should break once there are no more results left to scrape.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://www.centris.ca{}'
post_link = 'https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetInscriptions'
url = 'https://www.centris.ca/fr/propriete~a-vendre?view=Thumbnail'
unique_links = set()

payload = {"startPosition":0}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    
    s.get(url) #Sent this requests to get the cookies

    while True:
        r = s.post(post_link,json=payload)
        if not len(r.json()['d']['Result']['html']):break
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.json()['d']['Result']['html'],"html.parser")
        for item in soup.select(".thumbnailItem a.a-more-detail"):
            unique_link = base.format(item.get("href"))
            if unique_link not in unique_links:
                print(unique_link)
            unique_links.add(unique_link)

        payload['startPosition']+=12
```